# Use condition to get only records with non-numbers values in a fetchXml Dynamics CRM query

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I'm querying Dynamics CRM using fetchXML.
I have an entity that have attribute (placeName) where its value is either string or value of a number.
I would like to have condition that only the records with a non-number value should be selected.
I didn't find any solution for that in the dynamics documents, but maybe there is a solution using an "out-of-the-box" (custom condition). 
This is my current  fetch query:

```
<fetch mapping="logical" distinct="true" version="1.0">
  <entity name="locations">
    <attribute name="placeID" />
    <attribute name="placeName" /> // This can be values like "home" or 100 - I would like to take out only those which are not a number
  </entity>
```

Comment: did my answer help you achieve what you needed? if so, please mark it as accepted. if not, let me know so I can further help you.

Comment: @HeyJude - I didn't have the chance to check it yet. I'll update. Thanks

Comment: any update? did it work for you?

Comment: @HeyJude - no, not yet - it is election day today - no work - I'll try it tomorrow (meanwhile, I made a work around by filtering after getting the data) - promise to update !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I couldn't find it documented anywhere, you can use `like` operator with regex-ish syntax.

For example, the following query would retrieve `systemuser` records that only contains numbers in their `domainname`:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
   <entity name="systemuser">
      <condition attribute="domainname" operator="like" value="%[0-9]%" />
   </entity>
</fetch>
```

And in your case, the following would retrieve records only with letters a-z or A-Z:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
   <entity name="locations">
      <condition attribute="placeName" operator="not-like" value="%[0-9]%" />
   </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: A small update - It worked with the first Regex,  of the  numeric, but not with that of the alpha-beta. The good news is that there is an operator of "not-like", where you can combine with the numeric regex